# The correct way for generating "Execution plan" for a PL-SQL statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, query, execution-plan, plsql

I'm studying about `Explain plan and Execution plan` in Oracle and according to what I've read so far , The explained plan can differ from the actual plan used during statement execution. So I think execution plans are more useful for `optimization purposes` in comparison with explain plans.

My question :

How do you usually generate execution plan for a Sql statement? After reading different articles I'm a bit confused now because in each of them a different approach is introduced !
For instance I came across this one :

```
explain plan 
 set statement_id = 'ex_plan1' for

select phone_number
from employee
where phone_number like '650%';

select PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
 from table (DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY(STATEMENT_ID=>'ex_plan1'));
```

1. Is this the `correct way` for having the execution plan (not the explain plan)?
2. What are other ways for having the correct execution plan?(The one `that optimizer` has chosen to execute the statement).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to your 1st question**

NO this is explain plan and not execution plan.

EXPLAIN PLAN command - displays an explain plan for a SQL statement without actually executing the statement.

**Answer to your 2nd Question:**

Below will show execution plan of last executed SQL in the current session

```
Select plan_table_output from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'basic'));
```

Below will show execution plan of using SQL_ID:

```
Select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor('d1br5x9r1buhz',NULL,'all +predicate +cost'));
```

You can also use V$SQL_PLAN as ultimately this view is used to generate execution plan by DBMS_XPLAN

Please refer to below links for for clarity on this subject:

[Link1](https://sqlmaria.com/2017/08/08/using-dbms_xplan-display_cursor-to-examine-execution-plans/)
[Link2](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/how-do-i-display-and-read-the-execution-plans-for-a-sql-statement)